# How can I drag an active cell to the last column on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

When I say drag I mean using the small blue square in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Welcome. Have you faced a problem?

Answer (score 1):

- hoover your mouse cursor over that blue square
- left-click it and hold your click while moving mouse from current position to the right
- release your left-click when needed

picture shows this for ***rows in column*** but its same for ***columns in one row***:

[image]

**shortcut / hotkey usage:**

for a sole purpose to move that blue square there isnt any shortcut/hotkey. closest you can get is to use `SELECT` and `FILL`, however `FILL` will be performed **only** from **active cell** eg. **not** from **active range of cells**.

select leading cell and press:

- **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>➜</kbd>**+**<kbd>➜</kbd>**+**<kbd>➜</kbd>...** and then **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**
- **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>➜</kbd>** and then **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**

Comment: Guess I wasn't clear. I mean is there a shortcut

Comment: @Shabbs15 indeed you were. see my updated answer